# QT 4.4.3 build failing

Tags: compiling, qt4

I was trying to install `QT 4.4.3` on my Ubuntu machine.

I downloaded the *qt-all-opensource-src-4.4.3.tar* package and uncompressed it. Then `./configure` and then `make`. I got this steps from the install file in the package.

Errors shown when `make`:

```
Error 1 : recipe for target '.obj/release-shared/qsslcertificate.o' failed    
Error 2 : recipe for target 'sub-network-make_default-ordered' failed
```

Comment: what steps did you use and where did you get those steps from?

Comment: I downloaded the qt-all-opensource-src-4.4.3.tar package and untarred it. Then ./configure and then make. I got this steps from the install file in the package.